# How to execute event repeatedly in Python?

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I'm new to pygame programming. I need that operation increases character's speed (who is represented as moving images on screen) every 10 seconds using 'self.vel+=1'. Probably pygame.time.set_timer) would do it but I don't know how to use it. Because I use window with moving images, time.sleep wouldn't be good idea because then window would freeze. 
What should be the best option and how to use it?

Comment: Hi there. Can you post the code you've got so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple example using a timer. The screen is filled with a color that changes every 0.4 seconds.

```
import pygame
import itertools

CUSTOM_TIMER_EVENT = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
my_colors = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "purple"]
# create an iterator that will repeat these colours forever
color_cycler = itertools.cycle([pygame.color.Color(c) for c in my_colors])

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([320,240])
pygame.display.set_caption("Timer for Dino Gržinić")
done = False
background_color = next(color_cycler)
pygame.time.set_timer(CUSTOM_TIMER_EVENT, 400)  
while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        elif event.type == CUSTOM_TIMER_EVENT:
            background_color = next(color_cycler)
    #Graphics
    screen.fill(background_color)
    #Frame Change
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
pygame.quit()
```

The code to create the timer is `pygame.time.set_timer(CUSTOM_TIMER_EVENT, 400)`. This causes an event to be generated every 400 milliseconds. So for your purpose, you'll want to change that to `10000`. Note you can include underscores in numeric constants to make it more obvious, so you could use `10_000`.

Once the event is generated, it needs to be handled, so that's in the `elif event.type == CUSTOM_TIMER_EVENT:` statement. That's where you'll want to increase the velocity of your sprite.

Finally, if you want to cancel the timer, e.g. on game over, you supply zero as the timer duration: `pygame.time.set_timer(CUSTOM_TIMER_EVENT, 0)`.

Let me know if you need any clarifications.

[image: Running Example]

Answer (score 0):

Using Python's [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html) module you can time ten seconds while your code is running and increase the speed after ten seconds have passed.